# Android Gestures to Replace Physical Arrow Keys

Tags: android, touch, key, gestures

I'm starting from scratch and I don't even know where to look.. or even what to call this.. so any help would be appreciated.

I am working with the Snake example that Google supplies and I want it to work on Android devices without physical keys. How would I be able to use touch gestures (up/left/right/down) to make the snake turn and whatnot.

Again, I don't even know where to start looking.. I'm still slowly learning my way through programming for Android.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement `View.OnTouchListener`. I think [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) is the one you're looking for.

I would modify it so that touching the top part of the screen sent the snake up, the left side sent it left, etc.